# append successive dictionaries in Dataframe as rows

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following empty dataframe.

```
    columns = [
 'image_path',
 'label',
 'nose',
 'neck',
 'r_sho',
 'r_elb',
 'r_wri',
 'l_sho',
 'l_elb',
 'l_wri',
 'r_hip',
 'r_knee',
 'r_ank',
 'l_hip',
 'l_knee',
 'l_ank',
 'r_eye',
 'l_eye',
 'r_ear',
 'l_ear']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)
```

And in every loop, I want to append a new dictionary in this dataframe, with keys the column objects. I tried `df = df.append(dictionary, ignore_index = True)`. Yet only this message appears and the script never ends:

```
df = df.append(dictionary, ignore_index = True)
/home/karantai/opendr/projects/perception/lightweight_open_pose/demos/inference_demo.py:133: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
```

Can I append a new dictionary as new row in dataframe, in each loop?

Comment: You should first create an empty list and append all your dictionaries to it. Once you are finished only then create a new DataFrame using that list.

Answer (score 0):

As @Amer implied, it's not a good idea to append rows to a dataframe one by one, because each time a new dataframe object would have to be created, which is inefficient. Instead, you can merge all your dictionaries into one and then call `pd.DataFrame()` only once.

`defaultdict` is useful here, to automatically initialize the values of the full dictionary as lists. I would also use the `get` method for dictionaries, in case any one of your dictionaries is missing one of the keys. You can assign NumPy's `nan` as a placeholder for the missing values in that case.

In the end, `pd.DataFrame()` will pick up the column names from the dictionary keys. Here is an example with just three columns for simplicity:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

columns = ['image_path', 'label', 'nose']
dictionaries = [{'image_path': 'file1.jpg', 'label': 1, 'nose': 3},
                {'label': 2, 'nose': 2},
                {'image_path': 'file3.png', 'label': 3, 'nose': 1}]

full_dictionary = defaultdict(list)

for d in dictionaries:
    for key in columns:
        full_dictionary[key].append(d.get(key, np.nan))
        
df = pd.DataFrame(full_dictionary)
df
```

```
    image_path  label   nose
0   file1.jpg   1       3
1   NaN         2       2
2   file3.png   3       1
```